# How to execute a piece of code at a time picked with UIDatePicker in Swift 2

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift2

I have a date picker on my view controller and have connected it to the `ViewController.swift` file. I know to get the **date/time** picked by the user: I have to call `datePicker.date`.

My question is how would I run a piece of code at the time the user specifies **date/time** with `UIDatePicker` every day (I have the datePicker set to time mode)?

Comment: Can you please clarify what this piece of code is going to do? Is it a local notification which needs to be shown at the said time or what has to happen at the user chosen time?

Comment: I don't want to send a notification. I want to run a function a the specified time.

Comment: I am basically trying to execute a function a few seconds before I send a notification. I have the notification part working.

Comment: I'm not aware of this being possible without remote notifications. However, I know very little about your app so please review the [Background Execution documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) as you may find something relevant to your app.

Comment: I am trying to run a function before the notification is sent. The function will get the current weather conditions, then I want the notification to be sent with the current weather info. I added about 5 seconds to the time picked by the user, at the original time I want the function to be executed. I want this to happen everyday.

Comment: Maybe I could use NSTimer in someway